# How do I assign the result of eval to variable in bash script?

Tags: bash, variables, eval

I have a bash script that returns a list, which is what I want, but I need to put the results in a variable so I can operate on them one at a time in a for loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
processID="ps aux | grep `date +"%b"` | gawk '{print \$2}'"

eval $processID
```

How do I assign the result of eval to a variable?
Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? You don't need a variable to loop over command output, and [`eval` is almost always a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). You might also want to read up on [process management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Comment: I'm trying to operate on a list generated by another command. While I don't need a variable for command output, it seems to me that it makes things more readable for the future. Nonetheless, I accomplished my goal without using eval, though reading your reference assures me that it isn't wrong to do so.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Another bit of [applicable information](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 2):

```
pid=$( ps aux | grep `date +"%b"` | awk '{print $2}' )
```

Comment: Whether on the command line or in a script, I get an error about the backslash at \$2 not being the last character on the line. When I take it out, it runs ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can cut out the need for grep since you are already using awk. The "$" does not need to be escaped because expansions do not occur inside of single quotes.

```
pid=$(ps aux | awk -vdate=$(date +%b) '$0 ~ date { print $2 }')
```

If you expect multiple pids to be returned, use an array:

```
pids=($(ps aux | awk -vdate=$(date +%b) '$0 ~ date { print $2 }'))

for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
   ...
done
```

Comment: Thanks jordanm, You've given me a way to get a result, but you didn't answer the question I asked "How do I assign the result of eval to a variable?". The code was just an example.